# ReactJS - how to re-render a component after another choice is clicked on form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

Relatively new to React here, so forgive me if this is an easy fix.

I have a component that has a form - this form has 4 choices, and my intention is that every time you click an option on the form, a child component is rendered with data from the choice selected.

Here is the issue I am having. Currently, I'm able to load the child component upon my first choice selection, but I cannot reload the component unless I select the default value first.

Attached is my code: App.js; here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-agnesi-1wo7s

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

class App extends Component  {
    constructor(props)  {
        super(props);

        this.state = { 
          value: '',
          prevValue: '',
          submitted: false
        }; 
        
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({prevValue: this.state.value});
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        this.setState({submitted: true});
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render()    {  
        var renderingBool = false;

        if (this.state.submitted)   {
            if (this.state.value !== "--")   {
                renderingBool = true;
            }
        }

        return (
            <div className="Base">
                <h1> By Productline </h1>
                <form>
                    <label className="label">
                        Select Workflow: {"               "}
                        <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                            <option value="--"> -- </option>
                            <option value="test1">test1</option>
                            <option value="test2">test2</option>
                            <option value="test3">test3</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </form>

                <div>
                    {renderingBool && <ChildComponent history={this.props.history} detail={this.state.value}/>}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

ChildComponent.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class ChildComponent extends Component{
  constructor(props)  {
    super(props);

    this.input = props.detail;
  }

  render()  {
    return(
      <h1>{this.input}</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

I currently have this set up because if I do not have a boolean before calling the child component, I will not be able to render it. So, it makes sense that I have to set `renderingBool` to false (by selecting "--") and then set it to true again by selecting another choice, all in an effort to re-render the childComponent.

Is there a workaround to this? Can I re-render the child component without having to select the default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

Child component isn't reacting to updated props. You only see the updated value *after* switching the select value back to "--" and the component is remounted.

```
{renderingBool && ( // <-- when false, unmounts child
  <ChildComponent
    history={this.props.history}
    detail={this.state.value}
  />
)}

class ChildComponent extends Component{
  constructor(props)  {
    super(props);

    this.input = props.detail; // <-- only gets prop value when mounting
  }

  render()  {
    return(
      <h1>{this.input}</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

## Solution

Simply render props in the child

```
class ChildComponent extends Component{
  render()  {
    return(
      <h1>{this.props.detail}</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

## Suggestion

Set initial value to `"--"` and disable that option in the UI so it isn't selectable

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: "--", // <-- set initial select value
      prevValue: "",
      submitted: false
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      prevValue: this.state.value,
      submitted: true,
      value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Base">
        <h1> By Productline </h1>
        <form>
          <label className="label">
            Select Workflow: {"               "}
            <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
              <option disabled value="--"> -- </option> // <-- disable so it can't be chosen
              <option value="test1">test1</option>
              <option value="test2">test2</option>
              <option value="test3">test3</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </form>

        <div>
          {this.state.value !== "--" && (
            <ChildComponent
              history={this.props.history}
              detail={this.state.value}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-re-render-a-component-after-another-choice-is-clicked-on-form]

Comment: hey drew, thanks for your response! I have a follow up: is it possible that on every click of an option and the subsequent re-render of the childComponent, that I can get the childComponent to fetch a URL and retrieve the data? I've attached a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-fast-79j7n 

EDIT: the only way I can fetch is when I reset and set the choice to "--"

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that the problem is in ChildComponent, not your App component.

```
render()  {
    return(
      <h1>{this.input}</h1>
    );
  }
```

As you can see, you always render `this.input`. It is supposed to be assigned `props.detail`, but note that assignment only happens in constructor, which means it's not dynamic enough.

So, change your render method on ChildComponent to this.

```
...
<h1>{this.props.detail}</h1>
...
```

Comment: hey Hayden, thanks for your response! follow up:  is it possible that on every click of an option and the subsequent re-render of the childComponent, I can get the childComponent to fetch a URL and retrieve the data? here is a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-fast-79j7n

Comment: Can you explain more about what you want?

Comment: Hey Hayden, I actually asked a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63389766/reactjs-how-to-fetch-inside-a-child-component-with-details-passed-on-by-props