# ReactJS - how to fetch inside a child component with details passed on by props from a parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I have a component which has a form, and from that form you can select three options. Once either of these options is selected, a child component is rendered underneath. This child component needs to fetch data from a server based on the input.

The issue I am having is that although I am able to pass data down to the child component, the child component is unable to fetch unless I select the default option on the parent component and then select another value.

Here is my code:
codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-forest-7l0qb

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: "",
      prevValue: "",
      submitted: false
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ prevValue: this.state.value });
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    this.setState({ submitted: true });
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    var renderingBool = false;

    if (this.state.submitted) {
      if (this.state.value !== "--") {
        renderingBool = true;
      }
    }

    return (
      <div className="Base">
        <h1> By Productline </h1>
        <form>
          <label className="label">
            Select Workflow: {"               "}
            <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
              <option value="--"> -- </option>
              <option value="Lebron_James">Lebron James</option>
              <option value="Kobe_Bryant">Kobe Bryant</option>
              <option value="Lamar_Jackson">Lamar Jackson</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </form>

        <div>
          {renderingBool && (
            <ChildComponent
              history={this.props.history}
              detail={this.state.value}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

ChildComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ChildComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: ""
    };

    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData = () => {
    var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + this.props.detail;
    console.log(url);

    fetch(url)
      .then((results) => results.text())
      .then((results) => this.setState({ data: results }))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  render() {
    return <h1>{this.props.detail}</h1>;
  }
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

If I do not have a boolean before calling the child component, I will not be able to render it. So, it makes sense that I have to set `renderingBool` to false (by selecting "--") and then set it to true again by selecting another choice, all in an effort to re-render the childComponent. Is there a workaround this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `componentDidMount` runs when the component is `mounted` i.e. when it appears for the first time. Once you change the prop by selecting another value, it doesn't re-mount the component again, it just updates the prop and re-renders it.

If you want to fetch the data again when the `detail` prop changes you need to use `componentDidUpdate` along with `componentDidMount`

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.getData();
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.detail !== prevProps.detail) { // This prevents the update from going into an infinite loop
    this.getData();
  }
}
```